# Google adsense error message 'registerLandingUrlModifier' of null

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, adsense

Since some days ago, I'm getting the following error message in every web page I have adsense banners:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'registerLandingUrlModifier' of null"
```

I'm using the asynchronous scripts supplied by the Adsense site, and I didn't see this error message some days ago.
I can't find any reference in Google about this 'registerLandingUrlModifier' thing, any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It has disappeared... Now I got the classic "Blocked a frame with origin http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from accessing  a frame with origin (my url)"